# Two problems with a test phonegap app

Tags: cordova

I have downloaded the phonegap framework to test it, but I have encountered some problems in the beginning. I have successfully installed the framework and created a new project, but when I type "phonegap run android" in the console (in the folder of the project, ofc) I recieve the following three lines:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment
[phonegap] compressing the app...
```

and then it stucks and nothing happens.

When trying to run the index.html file in the beginning, I stuck at the screen "PHONEGAP connecting to device", but then again nothing happens.

Can someone help me and explain me how to get into the framework to test it.

Thanks a lot!
Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem. Just follow these steps.

Check your path variables.
The paths that have to be in your variable "Path" are (+ your old ones):

```
C:\Windows\System32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files\Java\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

So actually you need

> - Java.
> - The latest sdk (be sure you link to the tools and the platform-tools folders) (especially API level 17)
> - Apache Ant !! (YOU HAVE TO INSTALL ANT. I think this could be the solution)
> - nodejs (for phonegap and so on)
> - and git (for api-plugins)

If you installed everything try typing:

```
$ phonegap create "yourProject"
$ cd yourProject
$ phonegap local build android
```

then start your emulator
go on after starting the emulator:

```
$ phonegap --emulator run android
```